# Second MapRoute in asp.net MVC 4 doesn't work with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, maproute

i want to add a second MapRoute to my first MVC 4 Project, well i added this code in **Global.asax.vb**

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Math", _
        "Calculator/{action}/{foo}/{intBar}", _
        New With {.controller = "Calculator", .action = "Add", .foo = ""} _
    )
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Default", .action = "Index", .id = ""} _
    )
```

and this is my controller **/Controllers/CalculatorController.vb**

```
   Function Add(         ByVal foo     As String, 
                Optional ByVal intBar? As Integer = 1) As ActionResult
        ViewData("Message") = foo & " Welt"
        Return View()

    End Function
```

Now my problem, what i am doing wrong?

localhost:18118/Calculator/Add/Hallo
 - Message is only " Welt" but where is "Hallo" ?

localhost:18118/Calculator/Add/Hallo/7
 - Error 404 ? Why ?

I hope you can help/teach me. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact, that your two routes "Math" and "Default" are defining different **named** parameters
When you call:

localhost:18118/Calculator/Add/Hallo

Then the "Default" route is used and named parameters are:

- controller = calculator
- action = Add
- id = Hallo

But your *Action* `Add` requires parameter named `foo`. I would suggest, rename the foo parameter in the "Math" route mapping as **id**:

```
 routes.MapRoute( _
        "Math", _
        "Calculator/{action}/{id}/{intBar}", _ ' foo renamed to id
        New With {.controller = "Calculator", .action = "Add", .id = ""} _
    )
```

And rename the Action parameter as well: `Function Add(ByVal id As String,...` to make it working.

*NOTE: renaming is suggestion to make it working, not saying that this is the best way how to do that...*

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're overriding the `foo` param from the URL with the `.foo = ""` statement in the defaults object. You map `{foo}` in your route, so it takes in your 'Hallo' string -- but then you replace it with the empty string.

Try taking out `.foo = ""` from your defaults object.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but it seems that it doesn't work. I deleted the >> , .foo = "" << line in my defaults object but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: sorry about that -- I'm not familiar with the VB syntax. In C#, you initialize optional route values with 'UrlParameter.Optional'; I assumed VB made them optional with a straight assignment. Sorry for the wild goose chase!